how to animate symbols for only one way
How to animate the transition for likes, but not for unlikes?
@State private var liked = false

Button("Like", systemImage: liked ? "heart.fill" : "heart") {
    liked.toggle()
}
.symbolEffect(.bounce.up, value: liked)


See also Swift .symbolEffect disable under condition

You can use symbolEffectsRemoved to disable symbol effects.
Intuitively, .symbolEffectsRemoved(liked) would disable the symbol effect when liked is true, but this somehow doesn't actually work.
I managed to make it work by using a second @State though:
@State private var liked = false
@State private var disabled = false
var body: some View {
    Button {
        liked.toggle()
    } label: {
        Label("Like", systemImage: liked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
            .symbolEffectsRemoved(disabled)
    }
    .symbolEffect(.bounce.up, value: liked)
    .onChange(of: liked) { _, newValue in
        disabled = newValue
    }
}


If the same symbol is being used for both like and unlike then it is difficult to disable the symbol effect for a change from true->false but leave it enabled for false->true. You probably need a second state variable to get it working, as explained in the answer by Sweeper.
However, you can avoid the second state variable if you use two symbols and use opacity to control which one is visible:
Button {
    liked.toggle()
} label: {
    ZStack {
        Label("Like", systemImage: "heart.fill").opacity(liked ? 1 : 0)
            .symbolEffect(.bounce.up, value: liked)
        Label("Like", systemImage: "heart").opacity(liked ? 0 : 1)
    }
    .animation(nil, value: liked)
}

Instead of using two Label, you could also use an HStack with the two variants of the symbol:
Button {
    liked.toggle()
} label: {
    HStack {
        ZStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill").opacity(liked ? 1 : 0)
                .symbolEffect(.bounce.up, value: liked)
            Image(systemName: "heart").opacity(liked ? 0 : 1)
        }
        Text("Like")
    }
    .animation(nil, value: liked)
}

